# How to call event depening upon latitide and longitude?

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

i am developing a location base application. which determines  the latitude and longitude.

now i want to compare it with same values and if matched i want to call event.
i try it in many ways but unable to do it. kindly give an idea and code plz.
work that i did till now

Main activity

```
 package com.example.gpstracking;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidGPSTrackingActivity extends Activity {

Button btnShowLocation;

// GPSTracker class
GPSTracker gps;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);

    // show location button click event
    btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {        
            // create class object
            gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);

            // check if GPS enabled     
            if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                // \n is for new line
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your  Location    -          \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            }else{
                // can't get location
                // GPS or Network is not enabled
                // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                gps.showSettingsAlert();

            }

        }
    });
 }

 }
```

and sub activity

```
package com.example.gpstracking;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
 import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }       
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the onLocationChanged()-method that is already in your code. If the user moves, you can do your coordinate-comparison and then fire your event.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html

Update: This is the code that you could use to detect whether you reached a certain destination:

Make two variables for latitute and longitude in your class. So for example:

```
double lat=10.0;
double lon=5.0;
```

Then modify the onLocationChanged()-Method to something like this:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
 double currentLat=location.getLatitude();
 double currentLon=location.getLongitude();
 //you will need to create or reuse a distance-function... this should be easily findable...
 if (distance(lat,lon,currentLat,currentLon)<2.0){
 //do what you want to do...
 }
}
```

So for every location change that the phone detects, it will compare the distance to the last distance and fire the event...

Comment: dear i m getting an error. eclipse is not recognizing key word distance,
and for correction error it is giving hint to crate method "distance" having 4 parameter ...

how to fix it???

Comment: You can use the [android-maps-utils](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils) library. `SphericalUtil.computeDistance` is what you're after.