# how to take current location and compare it to other lolation or nearly about second location in android studio

Tags: android

I need full code that how can my application keep tracking the location of user and notify the user when he is near to the second location that i given in my application latitude etc

Comment: can anyone give me the answer

Answer (score 0):

take help of these examples for taking location coordinates.
[visit here](http://javapapers.com/android/android-location-fused-provider/)

and to compare refer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170131/comparing-two-locations-using-their-longitude-and-latitude)