# How to detect Nearst available lattitude and Longitude in Android App

Tags: android, geolocation

I have data of associates with their Longitudes and Latitudes. I want to detect the nearest associate to the User Location. user location i will detect with the Android SDK. 
My Question how to match the params in such a way that APP can show the best nearest associates. thanks in Advance.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170131/comparing-two-locations-using-their-longitude-and-latitude

Answer (score 0):

Considering your list of associates is non-null array of lats longs.

```
LatLng GetNearest(LatLng myPos, LatLng[] Associates)
{
    double nearestDistance = distance(myPos.lat, myPos.lng, Associates[0].lat,Associates[0].lng);
    LatLng Nearest = Associates[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < Associates.length(); i ++)
    {
       double _d =  distance(myPos.lat, myPos.lng, Associates[i].lat, Associates[i].lng);
       if(_d < nearestDistance)
      {
           nearestDistance = _d;
           Nearest  = Associates[i];

      }
    }
  return Nearest;
}

/** calculates the distance between two locations in MILES */
private double distance(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) {

    double earthRadius = 3958.75; // in miles, change to 6371 for kilometer output

    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);

    double sindLat = Math.sin(dLat / 2);
    double sindLng = Math.sin(dLng / 2);

    double a = Math.pow(sindLat, 2) + Math.pow(sindLng, 2)
        * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2));

    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

    double dist = earthRadius * c;

    return dist; // output distance, in MILES
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a `POJO` of `Associates`, in which you have `Longitudes` and `Latitudes` for each of your `associate`, So let's say you have an `Array` of associates then to find the nearest to user location, use this short and simple logic :

```
 for (Associates associate : associates) {
        Double associateLatitude = associate.getLatitude();
        Double associateLongitude = associate.getLongitude();

        android.location.Location locationOne = new android.location.Location("");
        locationOne.setLatitude(userLatitude);
        locationOne.setLongitude(userLongitude);

        android.location.Location locationTwo = new android.location.Location("");
        locationTwo.setLongitude(associateLongitude);
        locationTwo.setLatitude(associateLatitude);

        float distance = locationOne.distanceTo(locationTwo);
        if (disTemp == 0.0f) {
            disTemp = distance;
            nearestAssociate = associate;
        } else if (disTemp > distance) {
            disTemp = distance;
            nearestAssociate = associate;
        }
    }
```